# Slick2D nullPointerException failed to parse tilemap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, slick2d

i have a problem to display my TileMap with Slick2D framework.

This is my java code:

```
 package main;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.Input;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;

public class Play extends BasicGameState {
    boolean verlassen = false;
    private TiledMap map;

    public Play(int state) {

    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
        map = new TiledMap("res/Race.tmx");
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        map.render(0, 0);
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException {
        Input input = gc.getInput();

        if (input.isKeyDown(input.KEY_ESCAPE))
            sbg.enterState(0);
    }

    public int getID() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This is what my TiledMap looks like in Editor.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="50" height="50" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" nextobjectid="4">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="hexagonAll_sheet" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="4096">
  <image source="hexagonAll_sheet.png" width="2048" height="2048"/>
  <tile id="133">
   <objectgroup draworder="index">
    <object id="0" x="0" y="0.25" width="31.75" height="32"/>
   </objectgroup>
  </tile>
 </tileset>
 <tileset firstgid="4097" name="hexagonObjects_sheet" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="512">
  <image source="hexagonObjects_sheet.png" width="1024" height="512"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Background" width="50" height="50">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAAC+3XwRLCMAgE0OrVv/bQ7/baUdgsIQHqcNhbmvIIjeP5PI7z33IUj8WR3UumxwbH+5Wf6V4Xc4gWhyNyfoYeZrYKODTLHR2whhVzlXC/tqMdOyztaEc72jFynI9LJMduW9R5SM8uNoQ7Np3F7R1Rc4VmapUtw8GkmkOYXer/qNVTxKFaijlQvdBTyMHMD1xTzCHWxVju4GAtI08xh7iesQQ41NoGFqsh0mGdL8qivUPp0XIHsFjXT5+F0UHXJqz96S/r3uSwWuB6ds8Ah2oxOCx7uRyWPhN3sZZpw4zjsr/HrRpAH3Y5rs8wDqoW6zPK/Lu/X+J3brkBONDdAtdpDiazBqUPo+8RWr31eC2g3yZDtmPF+zMN3xZvsh2dTuev8gH223TuECcAAA==
  </data>
 </layer>
 <objectgroup name="object">
  <object id="1" x="191.333" y="544" width="96.3333" height="31.3333"/>
 </objectgroup>
</map>
```

I already read that there is a problem with the 'properties' which Slick is trying to parse.

```
Error Message: 
Mon Nov 09 17:58:15 CET 2015 ERROR:null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TileSet.<init>(TileSet.java:139)
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.load(TiledMap.java:661)
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.<init>(TiledMap.java:106)
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.<init>(TiledMap.java:90)
    at main.Play.init(Play.java:20)
    at main.Game.initStatesList(Game.java:22)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at main.Game.main(Game.java:35)
Mon Nov 09 17:58:15 CET 2015 ERROR:Failed to parse tilemap
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Failed to parse tilemap
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.load(TiledMap.java:695)
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.<init>(TiledMap.java:106)
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.<init>(TiledMap.java:90)
    at main.Play.init(Play.java:20)
    at main.Game.initStatesList(Game.java:22)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.init(StateBasedGame.java:164)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:393)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at main.Game.main(Game.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TileSet.<init>(TileSet.java:139)
    at org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap.load(TiledMap.java:661)
    ... 8 more
```

Can you help to fix this error ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through my own tmx files and the Slick2d source files, and I really don't get why your code won't run. My first thought was that you maybe HAD to specify some properties for the file to load, but my own tmx files don't use any properties (yet), and they run just fine!

Could you try:

1. Adding some properties to your tmx file? You shouldn't have to, but if it runs with properties you have at least isolated the problem
2. Although Slick2d is quite old now it's possible you are running an outdated version. Check wich version you are running and update if necessary. I think build 237 is the latest version
3. Try to make some more tmx files, and check  [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/)  to check if the version you have is outdated (although I doubt that is your problem)
4. If you are desperate you can download the Slick2d tiled package modify them so property loading is handled in a safer way (But I'm guessing step 2 will solve the problem ;) )

I see this question is 10 days old now.. So it's quite possible you've already found a solution. If so, could you post it here?

Comment: For this project i am not using TiledMaps anymore. I'll try to go trough your points most likely next week to test if it helps. I appreciate your help so far :)
Kind Regards